# error on line 6 expecting ) but it has enough of them

Tags: php, arrays, dictionary

Ok, so lets start with the code

```
<?php
function LuhnCalc($number) {
  $chars = array_reverse(str_split($number, 1));
  $odd = array_intersect_key($chars, array_fill_keys(range(1, count($chars), 2), null));
  $even = array_intersect_key($chars, array_fill_keys(range(0, count($chars), 2), null));
  $even = array_map(function($n) { return ($n >= 5)?2 * $n – 9:2 * $n; }, $even);
  $total = array_sum($odd) + array_sum($even);
  return ((floor($total / 10) + 1) * 10 – $total) % 10;
}

print LuhnCalc($_GET['num']);
?>
```

The errors are showing in the following lines

```
  $even = array_map(function($n) { return ($n >= 5)?2 * $n – 9:2 * $n; }, $even);


  return ((floor($total / 10) + 1) * 10 – $total) % 10;
```

The errors are

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ')' in
>   /home/MONKEY DO /public_html/gateway/crn.php on line 6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message says "I got a function but I expected a `)`". It's telling you that according to the grammar of the parser, the token `function` isn't expected to happen at that point. When you write `array_map(function(...` you are passing an anonymous function by using the token `function`, which the compiler doesn't like.

Anonymous functions were introduced in PHP 5.3. You're probably running and older version of PHP.  Check what version you're running, and upgrade if you need to.

Comment: there's no reason to update just for this.. you can convert array_map to use inline code

Comment: i am running PHP Version 5.3.13